# of([]) not considered an array

Tags: angular, rxjs

I currently have an rxjs data stream in my component:

```
items$ = of([]) as Observable<Item[]>;

ngOnInit(){
  this.items$ = this.httpService.getPokemonList();
}
```

However when I do the following in my unit testing it doesn't consider it an array:

```
component.items$.push({"slot": 1, "pokemon": {"name": "my test name pokemon", "url": "a url"}});

Error: Property 'push' does not exist on type 'Observable<Item[]>'
```

I'm assuming for this scenerio I can't use `of([]) as Observable<Item[]>`, is there another way to declare it?

Comment: You are trying to push an array type into an observable type ... The error is correct. Maybe do something like this.items$.pipe(tap(items => { items.push(yourItem); }));

Comment: It is unclear to me what you are trying to achieve. You want to push to the array, so why do you use Observable and not just a simple array? Also you are overriding the `items$` observable which is an RxJS antipattern.

Comment: `component.items$=of([{"slot": 1, "pokemon": {"name": "my test name pokemon", "url": "a url"}]);`

Comment: @JSONDerulo In unit testing since we never work with any real api data I have to mimic data. Therefore in the unit testing I have to push fake data and then (in my situation) do a fake click to view the further details.

Answer (score 2):

`items$` is just an `observable`. not an array.

You have to do like this.

```
const items: Item[] = [];
items.push({{"slot": 1, "pokemon": {"name": "my test name pokemon", "url": "a url"}});
component.items$.next(items);
```